# Django-storages S3Boto3Storage makes HEAD and GET requests on read

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

I am using the `S3Boto3Storage` storage backend from the `django-storages` package in my Django application. I use the backend to handle large amounts of files in S3.

When reading a file from the storage, the backend makes separate `HEAD` and `GET` requests. I am doing this operation many times, so I would prefer to skip the `HEAD` requests if possible.

My read operation looks similar to this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    img = FileField()

instance = MyModel.objects.filter().first()
instance.img.read()
```

I am using the default `preload_metadata` flag, which is `False`.

Is there another setting that controls this behavior of the read method?

My guess is that the `HEAD` request checks if the file exists before getting the file content. So maybe the `HEAD` call could be replaced with a try/except statement. But I could not figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**ATTENTION**: **Following solution is not for production, your lead will punish you if saw this in your code** :)

My packages version are old:
django-storages==1.1.8
boto==2.38.0
 
boto3==1.2.1
But main idea (I hope) will be understood

Place following patching(or if you wish - class could be extended) on some "start" level of your application(on your taste).

```
from storages.backends import s3boto


def monkey_init(self, name, mode, storage, buffer_size=None):
    """Only 'validate=mode != "rb"' was added in 'get_key' method's call"""
    self._storage = storage
    self.name = name[len(self._storage.location):].lstrip('/')
    self._mode = mode
    self.key = storage.bucket.get_key(self._storage._encode_name(name),
                                      validate=mode != "rb")
    if not self.key and 'w' in mode:
        self.key = storage.bucket.new_key(storage._encode_name(name))
    self._is_dirty = False
    self._file = None
    self._multipart = None
    # for files larger than this.
    if buffer_size is not None:
        self.buffer_size = buffer_size
    self._write_counter = 0


s3boto.S3BotoStorageFile.__init__ = monkey_init
```

In my version of `django-storages` call of method `get_key` doesn't pass `validate` variable into it. And I didn't find any way to force/change it except explicitly redefining `__init__` method.

PS: If your setting doesn't containt explicit `boto` section in logging -> logs will not be shown for GET/HEAD/etc. requrests from boto. Just add `boto` section into logging setting part.

```
'boto': {
    'handlers': LOGGING_HANDLERS,
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'propagate': False,
},
```